# Variable "organization_name" does not exist. In OroCommerce

Tags: php, symfony, orocommerce

I have created a new entity in OroCommerce: Task.php

```
class Task {

    private $id;

    private $subject;

    private $body;

    /**
     * @var Organization
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $organization;
    //Omit getter and setter methods
}
```

and the database has the task value.

Then I create a datagrids.yml in Resources/config/oro/

```
datagrids:
app-tasks-grid:
    options:
        frontend: true
    source:
        type: orm
        query:
            select:
                - task.id
                - task.subject
                - task.body
            from:
                - { table: AaxisTaskExampleBundle:Task, alias: task}
    columns:
        id:
            label: ID
            frontend_type: integer
        subject:
            label: Subject
        body:
            label: Body
    sorters:
        columns:
            id:
                data_name: task.id
            subject:
                data_name: task.subject
            body:
                data_name: task.body
        default:
            id: DESC
    filters:
        columns:
            id:
                type: number
                data_name: task.id
            subject:
                type: string
                data_name: task.subject
            body:
                type: string
                data_name: task.body
```

Then, I create a Controller and views

```
class TaskController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/task", name="aaxis_task_example")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function taskAction()
    {
        return [
            'entity_class'=> $this->container->getParameter('aaxis_taskexample.task.entity.class')
        ];
    }
```

and the views in Resources/views/Task/task.html.twig

```
{% extends 'OroUIBundle:actions:index.html.twig' %}
{% set gridName = 'app-tasks-grid' %}
{% set pageTitle = 'Task' %}
```

Last, i access the url like : http://localhost/task

it give me some error:
[Variable "organization_name" does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM64T.jpg)
How should I fix this error?

Thanks!!

-- Add Exception Stack Trace

> Variable "organization_name" does not exist.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
>
> Stack Trace
>
> in vendor/oro/customer-portal/src/Oro/Bundle/FrontendBundle/Resources/views/Organization/logo_frontend.html.twig at line 3   -
>
> {% set route = 'oro_frontend_root' %}
>
> {% if isDesktopVersion() %}
>
> ```
> {% if organization_name|length %}
>
>     {% set logo = oro_theme_logo() %}
>
>     <h1 class="logo logo-{{ logo ? 'image' : 'text' }}">
>
>         <a href="{{ path(route) }}" title="{{ organization_name }}">
> ```
>
> at Twig_Template ->getContext (array('assetic' => array('debug' => false, 'vars' => object(ValueContainer), 'use_controller' => false), 'app' => object(AppVariable), 'ws' => array('port' => '8080', 'host' => '*', 'path' => ''), 'commerce' => array('layout' => 'OroFrontendBundle::base.html.twig'), 'bap' => array('layout' => '::base.html.twig'), 'oro_ui_content_provider_manager' => object(ContentProviderManager), 'route' => 'oro_frontend_root'), 'organization_name')

Comment: Please provide more information especially for the organization-entity ... please provide also information about the controller which is rendering the template which is throwing an error ...

Comment: The organization-entity is an entity that comes with the orocommerce framework.